# redirect url using javascript/jquery (mobile)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, redirect

I have a problem here: I'm trying out to redirect my ulr to a specific url when a user gets log out(in a form). the problem is that this url: `http:champions2017/` have a form to log in and works perfecly well, but whenever a user clicks on log out button, my site redirects the url to `http:champions2017/auth/logout` where the session is destroyed, and the same log in form is displayed and here the problem comes out, here the user is unable to log in again, so I'm asking if there is a way to redirect to `http:champions2017/` once the session is destoyed. I know I can use `location.href` or a `header(location)` in php but no, I already did something like this: https://api.jquerymobile.com/navigate/ but no.

Comment: Please Follow this link. Your solution is here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-to-redirect-to-another-webpage-in-javascript-jquery

Comment: you are getting any error in second time click

Answer (score 0):

For redirect the page you can to use jQuery:

`window.location.href="http:champions2017/";`
`window.location.replace("http:champions2017/");`

You also can create `fn()` and call them as require.